Пропала кнопка переключения языков polylang
Пропала кнопка переключения языков с сайта. Стоит плагин polylang, все страницы есть и на русском и на английском, связаны, меню все продублированно также. Кнопка была, там же где кнопка корзины, два флажка. Редактировала эту кнопку. Сейчас ее нет, и нет возможности добавить виджет Language switcher, его просто нет в списке для добавления и все. В теме сайта есть возможность выбрать блок language switcher в разделе меню, выбрать не дает. Ставлю галочку, она при обновлении пропадает.

После некоторого обновления, нужно зайти в внешний вид > меню > настройки экрана > поставить галочку на пункте «переключатель языка»
